# Where should my PHP file live if I'm using AWS RDS to store user input into database?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, debugging

Before using Amazon RDS, I'd test my user input locally and my endpoint (`http://localhost/emails.php`) that of which would live inside my `htdocs` folder (I'm using MAMP) so I'd be able to store user input in my SQL db via text field without problems.

But now that I've moved onto Amazon RDS, I've gotten a new endpoint that successfully connects to MySQL Workbench.

My question is - Where am I supposed to store this php file that contains all the information to connect to my database, sql table, etc?  I want it to be able to work like how it worked locally before using RDS

I have code below for everything I just mentioned:

Here's my js file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class ProductList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        this.addFormData = this.addFormData.bind(this);
    }

    addFormData(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        const fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('myEmail', this.refs.myEmail.value);
        var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            // 'Host' : 'sdb.amazonaws.com'
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
        };
        axios.post("My AWS RDS Endpoint", fd, headers)
        .then(res => {
            alert(res);
        }).catch(err => {
            alert(err);
    });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                    <form>
                    <div className="col-xs-2 text-center">
                    <input type="email" id="Email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email" ref="myEmail" />
                </div>
                    <button type="submit" className="submitEmail btn btn-primary" onClick={this.addFormData}>Submit</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

here's my php file:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$servername = "my host";
$username   = "my name";
$password   = "my pw";
$dbname     = "mydb";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO mydb.emails
VALUES ('".$_POST['myEmail']."')";

echo $sql;

if (mysqli_query($conn,$sql)) {
    $data = array("data" => "You Data added successfully");
    echo json_encode($data);
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

?>
```

Here's my SQL query to create the table that holds emails:

```
CREATE TABLE mydb.emails(emails VARCHAR(200)); 
SELECT * FROM mydb.emails;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://localhost/*.php on your local system would be in your root folder on your host -- either htdocs, public or www.

axion.post() should be pointing to that .php file, not to the AWS endpoint.

It might be safer to put your RDS credentials in a separate file in a folder below your public folder in case for some reason there's an error that displays your PHP in plaintext. At least if you 'require' the file, you won't accidentally expose your credentials.

Comment: I gotcha.  But besides your point, am I doing things correctly in terms of storing the user input inside the db?  What I was thinking is that my php file should live somewhere inside the endpoint provided by AWS just like how I did it with localhost.  I just want to know if I got the concept down based on my code in my original post.

Comment: The PHP file will live on your server. Your $servername is where you will put the AWS endpoint. The AWS endpoint is the location of the database -- but the PHP file will live on your server/website.

Comment: The method of how you store the user email will succeed -- there are some problems in terms of security and data validation.  You can use filter_var to make sure that an email is entered (https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filter_var.asp).  And you should be using mysqli "prepared statements" to ensure that someone doesn't accidentally or purposely attack your database (see: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)

Comment: But I would suggest get it up and running first -- and then you can improve your code when you know it's working.

Comment: yeah I want to get it up and running first, that was my plan :).  I'm getting a 404 error `POST http://localhost:3000/my-aws-rds-endpoint 404 (Not Found)` upon clicking submit (localhost:3000 is my frontend host, I'm using React.js).  I think I found the problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm not supposed to put the AWS endpoint as a parameter in my `axios.post()` call and instead store the php file locally in my frontend and call the path to it? I tried that as well but to no avail :(.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207062/discussion-between-cloudyday-and-jeff-vdovjak).